# How can I use a visual image for the labels in my bar chart in Victory (React Library for Data Viz)

Tags: victory-charts

[Current Set Up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NgOyW.png)

I am using a bar chart to visualize data. On the Y-axis, I have categorical variables and I want to use images instead of the text labels. How should I go about doing that? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I looked into this and found the answer, hope it helps someone else stumbling upon this post some day :)

Using React:

Define your custom tick (containing the image):

```
const CustomTick = ({ x, y, text }) => {
    return <foreignObject x={x - 12} y={y - 8} width={16} height={16}><img src={imageSource} /></foreignObject>;
};
```

Use it in your chart (depending on which axis you'd like to show the image set  `tickLabelComponent` on either the axis with `dependentAxis` or the one without):

```
<VictoryChart ...props>
    <VictoryAxis tickLabelComponent={<CustomTick />} />
    <VictoryAxis dependentAxis />
    ...charts
</VictortChart>
```

Answer (score 0):

For react native using victory native you can show image as label by using following code. And here's a [snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@sadiac/petrified-cookies).

```
import { VictoryChart, VictoryBar } from 'victory-native';
import { Image } from 'react-native-svg';

<VictoryChart height={400}>
    <VictoryBar
      barWidth={20}
      horizontal
          alignment="start"
      style={{labels:{fill:"red", height:200}}}
      data={[
        { x: "09:00", y: 19.86 },
        { x: "12:00", y: 22.15 },
        { x: "15:00", y: 20.29 },
        { x: "18:00", y: 16.19 },
        { x: "21:00", y: 12.45 },
        { x: "29:00", y: 19.86 },
        { x: "22:00", y: 22.15 },
        { x: "35:00", y: 20.29 },
        { x: "58:00", y: 16.19 },
        { x: "01:00", y: 12.45 },
        { x: "01:88880", y: 12.45 },
        { x: "31:88880", y: 12.45 }
      ]}
      labels={({ datum }) => datum.y}
      labelComponent={<CustomLabelComponent />}
    />
  </VictoryChart>

function CustomLabelComponent(props) {
  const { x, y } = props;
  const imgHeight = 20;
  const imgWidth = 40;
  const padding = 0;
  return (
    <Image
      href={imgUrl}
      x={x - imgWidth / 2}
      y={y - imgHeight - padding}
      height={imgHeight}
      width={imgWidth}
    />
  );
}
```

For react, code is almost the same. [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/issue-1507-solution-forked-lxudi8) is an example. Courtesy of [narinluangrath](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/victory/issues/1507).